# how can i use a Ruby UDPSocket polymorphically with IO?

Tags: ruby, io, udp

what is the best practice for using a Ruby `UDPSocket` polymorphically with an `IO` object? i'm writing a serialization class for my library and want to treat network sockets the same as a `File` or a `StringIO` object, and `UDPSocket` does inherit from `IO`, but when i try to `write_nonblock`, the socket raises `Errno::EDESTADDRREQ`:

```
2.4.1 :1 > require 'socket'
 => true 
2.4.1 :2 > sock = UDPSocket.new
 => #<UDPSocket:fd 4> 
2.4.1 :3 > sock.bind('127.0.0.1', 0)
 => 0 
2.4.1 :4 > sock.write_nonblock 'nonblock'
Errno::EDESTADDRREQ: Destination address required
        from <internal:prelude>:136:in `__write_nonblock'
        from <internal:prelude>:136:in `write_nonblock'
        from (irb):4
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the socket must be [`connect`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html#method-i-connect)'d to a default address before you can `write` to it without specifying a destination through `send`:

```
2.4.1 :5 > sock.connect('127.0.0.1', 12345)
 => 0 
2.4.1 :6 > sock.write_nonblock 'nonblock'
 => 8
```